# How Can I Sort DataGrid Columns that is Inside DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I access The SalesOrderDetailLinesGrid and add SortDescriptions?
I've been trying a bunch of different ways but what I'm trying to do is when the row is expanded, I then want to gain access to the datagrid by name and add the SortDescriptions.

```
<DataGrid 
x:Name="MainGrid" 
ItemsSource="{Binding SalesOrderClassIEnumerable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSalesOrderLine, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

<DataGrid.Columns>
Stuff
</DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
       <DataGrid x:Name="SalesOrderDetailLinesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailSalesOrderLines}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailLine}"
          <DataGrid.Columns>
           Short By Column
          </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the `Loaded` event for the inner `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="SalesOrderDetailLinesGrid" Loaded="OnLoaded" ...
```

---

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid SalesOrderDetailLinesGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    //add sort descriptions...
}
```